# How to stop auto-casting when export the Access Table to .csv file

Tags: excel, vba, csv, ms-access

I would like to export a table in Access to Excel file.

There is a column in string format, like "01", "02".

When I use the ExportToCSV function, it automatically casted it into integer("01" -> 1), which I do not expected.

I tried to solve it by restating the column as String, but is doe not work. So I am wondering how to export the table with a specification of formating.

```
Public Sub ExportTables()
    Call ChangeToText("Coverage No")
    Call ChangeToInt("MY")
    Call ChangeToInt("MM")
    Call ChangeToInt("MD")
    Call ChangeToInt("Record Count")


    ' Export the Mortality table for DCS input
    Dim UserInput As String
    UserInput = CurrentProject.Path & "\DCS Capsil Expected Mortality_testing(2).csv"
    DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, , "DCS Capsil Expected Mortality", UserInput
    DoCmd.SetWarnings True
    MsgBox "Done!"
End Sub
```

Comment: Open the CSV in a text editor. How does it look there? I assume the conversion to number happens when you open the CSV with Excel.

Comment: Did you just format the field or did you "calculate" the fomatted string in the query?

Comment: @Andre Could I ban this conversion in Excel?

Comment: @WolfgangKais I just want to format the field, I need this indicator for later use.

Comment: Ok, Excel seems to make no difference... have you tried to export to Excel instead of CSV?

Comment: @WolfgangKais I have to export it as CSV since the later software could only handle the CSV file. I tried to use the export to Excel function and it worked to treat it as String. And this is how I did this work(Export to Excel and save as CSV), but I'd like to simplify this procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Create a query that calculates the formatted value for 2-digit numbers using an expression like

```
Format([MyField], "00")
```

This will be interpreted as text when exporting that query, and text is enclosed in text qualifiers by default. Although Excel will again show `1` instead of `01`, the csv file will contain `"01"` (enclosed in text qualifiers), so your target software can make use of it.